# Moveable GUI objects HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I am attempting to create a "local only" status board with moveable "GUI" objects.  Something to show physical location of items over a map.  I have very strict security requirements.  It would be best to have the items contained in a local file written in HTML or CSS.  I cannot use a lamp, wamp or any stack that requires a server and I cannot install additional software.

Impossible?

Answer (score 0):

To make Javascript work in a file viewed from the file system (as I see the challenge) you could write all your scripts in a script tag in the HTML file, and all your data as an object in that script block.